# Java Output right alignment

Tags: java, printf

I was wondering how would you use the `printf` in Java to align a string Output to the right?

Assuming I have 2 numbers, represented as a String. eg:

```
123,321,321,321 
    321,324,213+
```

How would I align them like that?

Its

```
System.out.printf( "%s something ", name) ;
```

I can't seem to find the `%` index online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int len = 15;
String spacer = String.format("%" + len + "d", 0).replace("0", " ");

String myNumber1 = "123,321,321,321";
String myNumber2 = "321,324,213";

System.out.println(spacer.substring(myNumber1.length()) + myNumber1);
System.out.println(spacer.substring(myNumber2.length()) + myNumber2);
```

This is called formatting. You can learn very interesting things [here](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [Apache Commons Lang StringUtils#leftPad](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29) also.