# Java: String format for a list

Tags: java, string

How does one format the following:

From this:

```
1: My street
2: 1232321
3: Hello there world!
4: A really really really long word!
```

To this:

```
1:                           My street
2:                             1232321
3:                  Hello there world!
4:   A really really really long word!
```

I think it has something to do with String.format() and a bunch of random chars in it!

Comment: What have you got with `String.format()`?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate or at least very similar question to  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640184/java-output-right-alignment). Take a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first split your string to get `1:` and `My Street` separately, and then format them: -

```
String str = "1: My street";
String str2 = "3: Hello there world!";

String[] arr = str.split("(?<=:) ");
String[] arr2 = str2.split("(?<=:) ");

System.out.printf("%s%30s\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
System.out.printf("%s%30s", arr2[0], arr2[1]);
```

**Output : -**

```
1:                     My street
3:            Hello there world!
```

You can do this with `String#substring` method also, to get the two parts separately.

```
System.out.printf("%s%30s\n", str.substring(0, 2), str.substring(3));
```